# Getting Error error message: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at te_analysis/transposonPSI_result_2fasta.pl line

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and in below script while executing, I am getting error

> `Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at te_analysis/transposonPSI_result_2fasta.pl line`

I think the issue is while assign `$_` value but not sure if that the cause.
How it can be fixed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my $largest = 0;
my $contig = '';
if (@ARGV != 2) {
  print "$0 fasta result\n";
  exit;
}

my $filenameA = $ARGV[0];
my $result = $ARGV[1];

my %seqs = ();

open(IN, "$filenameA") or die "oops!\n";

my $read_name = '';
my $read_seq = '';

while () {
  if (/^>(\S+)/) {
    $read_name = "$1";
    $read_seq = "";

    while () {
      if (/^>(\S+)/) {
        $seqs{ $read_name } = $read_seq;

        $read_name = "$1";
        $read_seq = "";
      } else {
        chomp;
        $read_seq. = $_;
      }
    }
  }
}

close(IN);

$seqs{ $read_name } = $read_seq;

open(IN, "$result") or die "oops";

open OUT, ">", "$result.fa"
   or die "oooooops\n";

while () {
  if (/Chain\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)-(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)-(\d+)/) {
    print "$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t$6\n";

    my $seq = substr($seqs{ $4 }, $5 - 1, ($6 - $5 + 1));
    print OUT ">$1.$2-$3.$4.$5-$6\n$seq\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: `while ()`... Shouldn't that be `while (<IN>)`? Both of them.

Comment: @MiladAghamohammadi Thanks for your effort on indentation. I propose however to be more careful with unrelated white-space habits of authors (i.e. where they place white space apart from indentation). I actually agree with your style, and cleaning indentation is obviously helpful. I also assume that not everybody agrees with my critique. But please try to keep as much "style" as possible untouched.

Comment: You have several occurrences of `while()`. Please explain each of it. Not all of them provide a context for using `$_`. I agree with @ikegami, how probably one case might be intended. But it seems unlikely that it solves all cases.

Comment: Putting line breaks in `$seqs{ $read_name }` was rather egregious, though. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing matches against the content of `$_` —`/.../` is short for `$_ =~ /.../`— but you never assign anything to `$_`.

Both instances of

```perl
while ()
```

should be

```perl
while (<IN>)
```

which is short for

```perl
while (defined( $_ = readline(IN) ))
```

I suspect you copied the code from an HTML document that wasn't properly constructed, causing the `<IN>` to be interpreted as an unknown tag rather than being displayed.

There may be other problems.

Comment: Thanks ikegami , after including <IN>.. it works...